# Don't show certain div on front page?

Tags: php, conditional-tags

I have CSS issues with a certain div only on the front page (front-page.php).
As I can't fix it, I was thinking about removing the item, but only on the front-page.

I'm not exactly sure how I have to code this in Wordpress.

I want this div in the Header to show up everywhere but on the front-page.php:

```
<!-- BEGIN TOP SEARCH -->

<form id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
                    <input type="submit" value="" id="searchsubmit"/>
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" value="Search or be lost" onfocus="this.value=''" />

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- END TOP SEARCH -->
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think japanworm *do not* want it on the frontpage, the code above let's it display *only* on the frontpage.

You can exclude something (if not) by putting an ! before the tag.
What you want to say is:

If it isn't front page than display the form

So it would actually be

```
<?php if( !is_front_page() ) { //if we are not on the front page ?>
the code of your form
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`is_front_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

```
if (!is_front_page()) { ?>
  <!-- BEGIN TOP SEARCH -->

    <form id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
      <input type="submit" value="" id="searchsubmit"/>
      <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" value="Search or be lost" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- END TOP SEARCH --><?php
}
```

Take a look at the list of [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). It is all in the Codex.

By the way, there is a stray `</div>`. That may be why this markup doesn't work the way expect.

Comment: No, it's part of a bigger div, so that has nothing to do with it. The end comment should probably be before the div.
I know about the conditional tags, but I wasn't sure how to implement it.

And I'm really thankful for your help, but if I use the code you provided then my side suddenly doesn't load anymore. No error message. Just doesn't load anything anymore. :(

Comment: Actually I got your code to work, but it has the opposite effect of what I want! It's only shown on the front page now.

Comment: Fixed. Should have had a `!`